# How to prevent an unregistered user from submitting a form multiple times

Tags: asp.net-core

I am developing a web application using ASP.NET Core Web API and React.js.

One of the requirements was to implement a contact form, from which all types of users could submit questions or ask for help. My initial idea was to use a smtp server to send that question via email.

Since using smtp's revolves around getting charged based on the number of requests, is there any efficient way of preventing the user from spamming or submitting that form multiple times?

One of the things that came to mind is memorizing the user's IP address, or assigning them a cookie. I'm not entirely sure whether that's doable and am curious to hear about workarounds and other opinions.

Comment: How about captcha?

Comment: @Felix Could you clarify with more details? That could prevent the form from being spammed programmatically, but the user could still solve the captcha multiple times and therefore submit the form multiple times. Or am I missing something?

Comment: no, you are correct. Typically, if the user goes through the trouble of filling form multiple times - it's not spamming, and application administrator is expected to respond. If you want to limit manual submissions - then it is not really a programming question (let alone as.net core question). you can force user to create an account, or track IPs, or create a unique ID in local storage. Obviously, everything can be bypassed. The question becomes how much you want to alienate the user to save a penny or less (if that!) on the email

Comment: `force user to create an account` I agree with @Felix I think a good system must have a good user management module. Even user can visit the site as a tutorial, but when he wanna start a contact, he need an account.